# Error when run model sequential image classification: Model was constructed with shape (None, 100, 100, 3) for input KerasTensor

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning, image-classification

So i was trying model from kaggle for image classification for fruit

link : https://www.kaggle.com/code/aninditapani/cnn-from-scratch-with-98-accuracy

but i got error when running the model, i was trying another model but got no error. im trying this model because want to get better accuracy

how i load dataset :

```
from sklearn.datasets import load_files
import numpy as np

train_dir = 'fruits-360_dataset/fruits-360/Training'
test_dir = 'fruits-360_dataset/fruits-360/Test'

def load_dataset(path):
    data = load_files(path)
    files = np.array(data['filenames'])
    targets = np.array(data['target'])
    target_labels = np.array(data['target_names'])
    return files,targets,target_labels
    
x_train, y_train,target_labels = load_dataset(train_dir)
x_test, y_test,_ = load_dataset(test_dir)
print('Loading complete!')

print('Training set size : ' , x_train.shape[0])
print('Testing set size : ', x_test.shape[0])
```

change data to categoriacally :

```
from keras.utils import np_utils
y_train = np_utils.to_categorical(y_train,no_of_classes)
y_test = np_utils.to_categorical(y_test,no_of_classes)
```

make validation set:

```
x_test,x_valid = x_test[12000:],x_test[:12000]
y_test,y_valid = y_test[12000:],y_test[:12000]
print('Vaildation X : ',x_valid.shape)
print('Vaildation y :',y_vaild.shape)
print('Test X : ',x_test.shape)
print('Test y : ',y_test.shape)
```

convert image to array:

```
from tensorflow.keras.utils import array_to_img, img_to_array, load_img

def convert_image_to_array(files):
    images_as_array=[]
    for file in files:
        # Convert to Numpy Array
        images_as_array.append(img_to_array(load_img(file)))
    return images_as_array

x_train = np.array(convert_image_to_array(x_train))
print('Training set shape : ',x_train.shape)

x_valid = np.array(convert_image_to_array(x_valid))
print('Validation set shape : ',x_valid.shape)

x_test = np.array(convert_image_to_array(x_test))
print('Test set shape : ',x_test.shape)

print('1st training image shape ',x_train[0].shape)
```

make model:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(filters = 16, kernel_size = 2,input_shape=(100,100,3),padding='same'))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=2))

model.add(Conv2D(filters = 32,kernel_size = 2,activation= 'relu',padding='same'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=2))

model.add(Conv2D(filters = 64,kernel_size = 2,activation= 'relu',padding='same'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=2))

model.add(Conv2D(filters = 128,kernel_size = 2,activation= 'relu',padding='same'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=2))

model.add(Dropout(0.3))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(150))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.4))
model.add(Dense(81,activation = 'softmax'))
model.summary()
```

this is how model running

```
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',
              optimizer='rmsprop',
              metrics=['accuracy'])

batch_size = 32

checkpointer = ModelCheckpoint(filepath = 'cnn_from_scratch_fruits.hdf5', verbose = 1, save_best_only = True)

history = model.fit(x_train,y_train,
        batch_size = 32,
        epochs=30,
        validation_data=(x_valid, y_valid),
        callbacks = [checkpointer],
        verbose=2, shuffle=True)
```

i dont know which one problem it is, because the input already image size 100x100 and working on another code for making model

```
WARNING:tensorflow:Model was constructed with shape (None, 100, 100, 3) for input KerasTensor(type_spec=TensorSpec(shape=(None, 100, 100, 3), dtype=tf.float32, name='conv2d_8_input'), name='conv2d_8_input', description="created by layer 'conv2d_8_input'"), but it was called on an input with incompatible shape (None,).
```

i was trying to try another model with same dataset which is 100x100 image size, but on this model cant work properly.

Comment: Please provide more code. How do you load `x_train`, `y_train`, `x_valid` and `y_valid`?

Comment: Also the code in your question is identical to the code in the notebook you provided. Notebook code runs just fine.

Comment: it is allowed to share code use google collab, i will share my code if its allowed here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the error message suggests the problem is in the way that you load your data. You are expected to pass an input of size `(None, 100, 100, 3)`. For this I would change the way you have programmed `load_dataset`. Check if the data is loaded correctly. Since you are working with image data, also have a look at `tf.keras.utils.image_dataset_from_directory` from `tensorflow`.